# Kotlin Completion Dialog Popup after Typing "object."

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm starting to use Kotlin for writing tests and coming from Java I'm used to a completion dialog when typing "." after an object. Like this:

[image: java completion example]

Doing the same thing using Kotlin does this:

[image: kotlin completion dot]

Even hitting Ctrl + Space doesn't work:

[image: kotlin completion dot ctrl space]

I only start to get suggestions when I start typing the first few letters of a function that I know exists. Example:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get Kotlin auto-complete working like Java?

I'm using the following version of IntelliJ IDEA on Ubuntu Linux with Oracle Java 8.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA version]

Comment: Are you sure you get that repeatedly? Because sometimes autocompletion plugin has to load itself  and lags (same thing with java)

Comment: It's definitely repeatedly. I've never got this to work like I expect it to. All pictures above were taken after the IDE had been running for hours and I waited about 10 seconds for each picture to make sure it was stable and the IDE wasn't lagging.

Comment: @voddan does your auto-complete work like I expect it to?

Comment: yes it does. No of that kind problems ever. Sometimes the project structure might be mixed up, but in that case there are no completion at all.

Comment: I recommend you sending a bug report with a memory snapshot here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by navigating to `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` and pressing "Invalidate and Restart"

Comment: In my case I was restarting IntelliJ to fix. This issue didn't seem anywhere near as common in Java.